# NServiceBus and Azure Service Bus message lost

Tags: c#, azure, iis, nservicebus, azureservicebus

I've been experiencing a weird but reoccuring behavior when using NServiceBus and Azure Service Bus.

When publishing the API, I notice that sometimes (sadly this is not stable behavior that will occur every time) where the processing of the request appears to be completed but the message does not arrive in the destination queue.

This is hard to reproduce, since the behavior is not occurring with every deployment, but here's at least the basic processing of the request:
Using the model, I create a command, and use this to send it over an injected IBus. There is no database interaction besides the authentication. The bus itself is created using the following configuration:

```
var configuration = new BusConfiguration();
configuration.EndpointName("Api");
configuration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(c => c.ExistingLifetimeScope(container));
configuration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
configuration.AzureConfigurationSource();
configuration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();


var conventionsBuilder = configuration.Conventions();
conventionsBuilder.DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Abc.") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"));
conventionsBuilder.DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Abc.") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"));
conventionsBuilder.DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Abc.") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("RequestResponse"));

ISendOnlyBus bus = Bus.CreateSendOnly(configuration);
```

I've tried the following methods to reproduce it locally:

- Start local emulator while hitting the local development endpoint every 20ms.
- Use local IIS.
- Use local IIS with a one minute timeout and hitting it every 90 seconds for 5 seconds.
- Use local IIS with recycles + stop and starts

Locally I've not been able to reproduce, every message always arrived.
On Azure it runs on a small cloud service.

Any thoughts or pointers would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the message is not getting into the dead letter queue or simply not being visible and re-appearing after some time?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure! They're not in the dead letter queue, nor re-appear after some time.

Comment: I know the dev for the Nservice <-> Azure integration and I asked him to jump on the thread. Maybe he has a better idea. I'm not sure if he will find the time, but it worth a try.

Comment: Are you seeing any exception being logged at around the same time that you see the behavior?

Comment: There was nothing in the logs as far as we could see. It almost seems like NServiceBus is not initialised.

Comment: So to sum up, you are sending through an ISendOnlyBus instance, from within a controller. Sometimes the message ends up on the queue and sometimes it does not, and you are not getting any exceptions at all? 

Can you share your implementation that invokes the send operation as well as your messagemappings definition? Maybe the message is routed somewhere else? Is there something listening on the destination queue or not?

Comment: Can you stop whatever the receiving part of your messages is and inspect if messages get to the queue and accumulate?

Comment: Yves, your summary is correct! I'll be in the office tomorrow and dive deeper. It doesn't seem to be a message mapping since they always turn up in the right queue when they arrive.
Yves and Sean, the listeners have been turned off at the points of testing precisely because we wanted to track the arrival in the queue better.

Comment: I wonder if your controller is calling Bus.Send in a transaction scope? If so, can you try to wrap the send call in a new 'Suppress' scope and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: The listeners have been turned off (for this) because we wanted to track queue arrival better.
I stumbled upon [1] indicating we already receive traffic after the RoleEntryPoint.OnStart returns true, while we do all our NServiceBus setup logic in Application_Start and some on INeedInitialization. This seems like it might help. 
Will try the Suppress scope as well, any idea why that might be an issue?
Will report back! It's really hard to tackle since it doesn't occur every time, replicating (and testing) is hard. 

[1] https://github.com/mspnp/azure-guidance/blob/master/Background-Jobs.md

Comment: The azure servicebus client actively checks whether it is invoked in a transactionscope that already has another resource, such as a database connection, enlisted in it. If it is, which is usually the case, it will throw an exception stating that it cannot be used together with another transactional resource. But as it is so common, we decided to work around this case by enlisting a volatile resource in the scope, which then would perform the send on commit of the scope. The downside of this approach is that callback can be invoked on a background thread and we can't marshal the exception back

Comment: If such an exception occurs, we retry the operation, but after several retries we have to give up with no way back to your calling code and drop the message. This could be the source of occasional message loss, however such an occurence is always logged so that you know of it, but given there are no entries in your logs it's probably not the case.

Comment: There are different ways to solve this transaction dilemma, but in your case the appropriate way seems to be to simply supress the transaction and send transactionless. As the SB resource manager isn't playing along with your database transaction resource manager anyway, and your means of invocation (http call) is non transactional as well, it makes no difference if you send in a transaction or not, so you can just disable this behavior by supressing.

Comment: Thanks @YvesGoeleven! I'll try your suggestion tomorrow. Does the difference between RoleEntryPoint.OnStart vs Application_Start and INeedInitialization sound like it could be that (somehow NSB not being fully initialized when the first request hits) or do you think it's not applicable?

Comment: A bus started in the role entry point would be a different one than the one hosted in the w3wp process, so it won't be applicable.

Comment: @YvesGoeleven added the supressed transaction scope. Will report back when more information arrives. Thanks for your help so far!